# Refresh page after login with litespeed cache

Tags: php, functions, login, cache

I am using the litespeed cache plugin and ajax login plugin. The page does not refresh after users log in. it actually seems to be refreshing, but no. I can not.

```
    // $form.data("action") for get
                $(document).triggerHandler('lrm/ajax_response', [response, $form, $form.data("action")]);

                // If user Logged in After Login or Registration
                // If Email Verify after Registration enabled - we skip this
                if (response.success && response.data.logged_in) {
                    LRM.is_user_logged_in = true;
                    $(document).triggerHandler('lrm_user_logged_in', [response, $form, $form.data("action")]);

                    if (LRM.reload_after_login) {
     window.location.reload(true);


                    }
                }
```

**window.location.reload(true);** this code not working.

Comment: Why bother using AJAX login at all if you need to refresh the page anyway? I would have thought the whole point of an AJAX login was so that you didn't need to refresh.

Comment: @JacobPeattie because, I am using a cache system.

Comment: I don’t see what that has to do with what I asked? Why are you using an AJAX log in plugin? What does it do for you?